# UK Immigration Control: Will henna/mehndi on my hands cause a problem?

Tags: air-travel, uk, removal

I have plans to travel to the UK. This is the first time I will be going abroad. It would be a two week trip.

My question is, if I put mehndi or henna on my hands before I go, is it going to create any problem for me?

I wouldn't have put it on but my sister's wedding is just two days before I leave for the UK.

Comment: Tattoos are not problem, why on earth would henna be a problem?

Comment: They don't care.  At the very most the IO will spot the henna and enquire who is getting married and if it's a forced marriage or not.

Comment: Like SpaceDog I'm another random dude on the internet with no official role in anything to do with travel. I've travelled internationally 'a reasonable amount'. I assume you are from India or nearby - maybe not. There is certainly nothing against the use of Henna "decoration" or tatooing in the UK - there are places where very heavy tatooing may be "noticed" but not where you are going.  I would be immensely surprised if anyone noticed Henna markings except as a positive attribute in your case. If you were of "classic pale skin, blonde hair ..."  Scandinavian stereotyped appearance the ....

Comment: .... Henna markings may attract slightly more attention due to being less usual but even then you would not expect any negative reactions. || FWIW: If you met me while travelling and were suitably adorned with Henna I may well ask if I could add your photo to my [**Random Strangers**](http://j.mp/RANDOMSTRANGERS) photo collection :-)

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly OK, the henna will pose no problems for you.

I wish I could give you a definitive quote or a link for this, but I've looked and I can't. Basically it's such a non-issue that nobody seems to have ever put down something official. I even tried to find an image of someone with henna in a UK airport without success.

So, just take the word of some random dude on the internet, I know people who've traveled with henna decorations on their hands and, honestly, it'll not cause a problem.

Comment: @pnuts Agreed. I suspect there may be a some concrete information out there somewhere, possibly not in English, but I couldn't find it. I hate doing "I know because I know" answers but I wanted to try and post to reassure the questioner because, well, I do know.

Comment: For that reason I hope @bedi will return here to share the first hand experience. That would be valuable.

Comment: @SpaceDog, I used to work the arrivals and detention at Heathrow/Gatwick as an [IAS (charity) representative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigration_Advisory_Service) for quite some time. I think your answer is fine,  It's not the word of GOD, but at least something to go on.

Comment: "For that reason I hope @bedi will return here to share the **first hand experience.**" - I see what you did there.